# Is there dbgview for .NET4?

Tags: .net-4.0

DebugView for Windows is an awesome tool which doesn't work for .NET4 apps.

Does anyone knows any other 3pty tool which can be used instead of dbgview?

[DebugView for Windows MSDN link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works fine if the .NET4 app writes to the "correct" location.

In particular, it needs to funnel through: the windows OutputDebugString or DbgPrint functions. The process that performs the write is not important. Using DefaultTraceListener should be fine; make sure it really is added to the listeners.

There is also an issue/bug I ran into in VS2010 in which the debug output inside VS2010 will prevent the output from being sent to OutputDebugString correctly (I'm not exactly sure why, but disabling it worked fine) and VS2010 also likes to spew random internally debugging nonsense. (This issue does not occur if the code is not run under VS2010 debugging iirc, but my memory isn't that good.)